# About $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \frac{1}{\lambda_2} \frac{1}{\lambda_3} \frac{1}{\lambda_4}$ (Gilbert Strang's lecture on YouTube)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, problem-solving

I am watching Gilbert Strang's lecture on YouTube.

I think his answer to [this problem](https://youtu.be/QuZL5IKpO_U?t=1538) is not perfect.

Is his answer ok?

> Let $A$ be an invertible $4$ by $4$ matrix.
>   Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$ be the eigenvalues of $A$
>
> Prove that $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \frac{1}{\lambda_2} \frac{1}{\lambda_3} \frac{1}{\lambda_4}$.

His answer is like the following:
$\frac{1}{\lambda_1}, \frac{1}{\lambda_2}, \frac{1}{\lambda_3}, \frac{1}{\lambda_4}$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$.
So, $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \frac{1}{\lambda_2} \frac{1}{\lambda_3} \frac{1}{\lambda_4}$.

I think he needs to show the multiplicity of a eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ of $A^{-1}$.
But he didn't show the fact.
So I think his answer is not perfect.
Am I correct or not?

By the way, my anser is the following:
$1 = \det(I) = \det(A A^{-1}) = \det(A) \det(A^{-1}).$
And
$\det(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \lambda_4$.

So, $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)} = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \lambda_4}$.

Comment: Often, when listing eigenvalues, people will list them a number of times equal to their multiplicity. For example, you might list the eigenvalues of the $4 \times 4$ identity as $1, 1, 1, 1$. If this is the convention being used, then is calculation is correct.

Comment: $A$ is similar to an upper-diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $\lambda_i$. Hence $A^{-1}$ is similar to an upper-triangular matrix with diagonal elements $1/\lambda_i$. Now take the determinant - done. The determinant of similar matrices is equal.